# jQuery UI dialog bug when dialog is resized then closed pushing X on IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am creating a new jQuery UI dialog and then resizing it to a higher height.
When I click the close button (X), the dialog moves up to the top of the screen instead of closing itself.

This occurs only in Internet Explorer (IE9 in my case).

Any workarounds to this?

Here's the js fiddle reproducing this bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/5WJBR/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dialog').dialog();
  $('#dialog').dialog('option','height', '1000');
});
```

I managed to make it work by removing the vertical scrollbar using css overflow-y:hidden but I in my use case I definitely need the vertical scrolling activated.

Thanks for any help,
Jimmy

Comment: Apologies, we accidentally deleted your UI ticket.  But as I mentioned in the ticket your test case was made against an older version of jQuery UI (1.9.2). This works fine on master:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q64GR/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer TJ. I actually posted the UI ticket 4 times struggling against the captcha that wouldn't go through.

Problem is I've tried upgrading the app to jQuery UI master but then this bug is solved but I get other incompatibilites between other plugins (such as dialog extend,...). Since the app is already in prod, I cannot afford to do the upgrade right now, a quick fix would be better.
Any hint on where should I start in jquery-ui-1.9.1.js to fix this bug? Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you could do here.  The dialog widget went through a rewrite in 1.10 so it's hard to say what would've fixed your problem.  Your best bet is to look through the changelog for 1.10 and see if you can figure out what fixed your problem: http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0.

Comment: Obviously the best thing to do would be to upgrade to 1.10+ but I realize that it might not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the fix for those interested (applies only for jQuery UI version 1.9.1 and below):

```
var that = this;
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').on('mousedown', function({
    that.dialog.dialog('destroy');
});
```

FYI, binding the titlebar on the 'click' event will not work!! Mousedown does.

Thanks,
-J